# Shortcut or command for macOS File Sharing system setting?

Tags: file-sharing

Is there some shortcut, app, widget, etc. — or, alterntively, a Terminal command-line command — that allows quick toggling on File Sharing under macOS (and subsequently, to toggle it off again)?

Since I often need to do this in order to share with another Mac, the best thing would be an icon in the Menu Bar to do the toggling.

What one has to do otherwise is open System Settings, then either:

1. type "file sharing" in the search field, click the "File sharing" item that is found, and finally move the File Sharing slider to On; or else
2. navigate to General, select Sharing, and finally move the File Sharing slider to On.

My environment: macOS Sonoma 14.1.

Answer (score -1):

When sharing with other Macs on my LAN, I use Apple's dedicated Screen Sharing app. I access it through Launchpad. Set up with Sonoma is described in [Share the screen of another Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mh14066/mac).

Comment: No, I'm not asking about screen sharing. I'm asking about FILE sharing!